# Looking for Delete statement for this Select statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datagridview, sql-delete

I have a DB in production and have been brought in to make changes. All going well except I can't get a DELETE to execute. I know it's because of joins and incorrect ref. integrity etc. but I can't really change that.
The select statement below executes without issue and displays in gridview:

```
SELECT 
  [Stock Inventory].MaterialNumber, 
  [Stock Inventory].[Optimum Stock] AS Optimum_Stock, 
  customerservice.Part, 
  customerservice.SamplesRequired, 
  customerservice.Frequency, 
  customerservice.Country 
FROM 
  [Stock Inventory] 
  INNER JOIN customerservice 
    ON [Stock Inventory].MaterialNumber = customerservice.Part
```

I am looking to use the delete link that is part of the generated table
If I have not provided enough information, please let me know

Comment: It should be `DELETE s
FROM [Stock Inventory] AS s
INNER JOIN customerservice AS c ON s.MaterialNumber = c.Part`

Comment: Error. I'll look into it shortly but this is what was returned:        The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Stock Movement_Stock Inventory". The conflict occurred in database "WarehouseSamples", table "dbo.Stock Movement", column 'MaterialNumber'.

Comment: Three things: Which table you have to delete from - [Stock Inventory] or customerservice? What is the relation between them? Is there a relation between any of those tables and other tables?

Comment: @JohnR - It is not because of the `DELETE` statement, the `DELETE` statement is correct, but this is because the foreign key constraint between the two tables, you can't delete the data that are referenced into another table, you have to delete the data from the referenced table first then from the second table, or use `CASCADE DELETE` in the definition of the foreign key

Comment: I actually need to delete from both. The CS table is what I added myself lately and contains the most up-to-date info regarding materials. I am only displaying the materials that exist in both the CS table and the [Stock Inventory] table as there is new information being tied to that material from the CS table. I did add the following this morning, which is now causing my delete problem `alter table dbo.customerservice
with NOCHECK
add constraint customerservice_part_FK FOREIGN KEY ( Part) references dbo.[Stock Inventory](MaterialNumber)`

Comment: One solution to this is to make the delete statement delete all the referenced data, by adding `ON DELETE CASCADE` to the foreign key constraint definition, see [**Cascading Referential Integrity Constraints**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: What I really need now is to remove the FK constraint. Any ideas?

Comment: No, Don't remove the foreign key, just alter the table and use the same statement but add `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: There's no way for a *single* `DELETE` statement to affect multiple tables, except via cascading deletes on foreign keys. So you either need two separate delete statements or you need cascading delete on your foreign key.

Comment: First: `alter table dbo.customerservice drop constraint customerservice_part_FK`. 2nd: `alter table dbo.customerservice
with NOCHECK
add constraint customerservice_part_FK FOREIGN KEY ( Part) references dbo.[Stock Inventory](MaterialNumber) on delete cascade`. Now when I run the delete, I get the follwoing error suggesting another FK issue: `The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Stock Movement_Stock Inventory". The conflict occurred in database "WarehouseSamples", table "dbo.Stock Movement", column 'MaterialNumber'.
The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: I should explain that the Stock movement table records all transactions as materials are added to [Stock Inventory] or removed. It should be OK to have a transaction take place, record it and, at some point in time, remove that stock completely from inventory

Comment: There is a `[Stock Movement]` (SM) table that references `[Stock Inventory]` (SI) table. There is a `customerservice` (CS) table that references `[Stock Inventory]` table as well. Both SM and CS depend on SI. First delete from SM records that are referencing SI JOIN CS. THEN issue a delete proposed by Mahmud.

Comment: If I am correct in my understanding, You are asking me to delete the record from the `(SM)`table prior to running the provided `DELETE`statement? Unfortunately , the `(SM)` records are required regardless of whether the material exists in `(SI)` any more or not

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned needing to delete from both tables you could do something like this:

```
begin transaction

declare @deleted table (MaterialNumber int) --whatever data type you need
DELETE s
output deleted.MaterialNumber into @deleted
  from [Stock Inventory] as s
  INNER JOIN customerservice as c
    ON s.MaterialNumber = c.Part


DELETE c
from customerservice as c
join @deleted d
    on d.MaterialNumber = c.Part    

commit transaction
```

Comment: This uses the deleted pseudo table in order to keep track of the ids deleted from the [Stock Inventory] table so that you can then delete the target records from the customerservice table.  Depending on your referential integrity, you may need to reverse the order or setup cascading delete, etc.